# Finding Value of Parameter that makes Eigenvalue equals to Zero (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue

Lets say I have a 2x2 matrix

```
  {b+2 b}
  {-4  5}
```

How should I approach this problem using Matlab to find the values of *b* where it gives me the eigenvalue is 0?

Comment: Solve the equation that the determinant of this matrix equals 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Yvon has eloquently stated, you would simply determine the values of `b` that would make the determinant of that matrix equal to 0.  If you recall from linear algebra theory, the eigenvalues of the matrix can be found by solving this equation:

```
det(A - lambda*I) = 0
```

`A` would be the matrix you are finding the eigenvalues for, `lambda` would be the eigenvalues of your matrix and `I` is the identity matrix that has the dimensions of `n x n`, where `n` has the same number of rows/columns as `A`.  Note that eigenvalues can only be found with square matrices.  In addition, linear algebra theory states that you will have `n` eigenvalues for the matrix.  Because you are expressly stating that one of the eigenvalues is 0 and want to solve for `b`, this simplifies to:

```
det(A) = 0
```

You can actually solve this by hand by computing the determinant of the 2 x 2 matrix by simply doing `xz - yw`, given that your matrix is of this form:

```
[x   y]
[w   z]
```

Therefore, in your case, we have:

```
(b+2)*5 - (b)*(-4) = 0
5*b + 10 + 4*b = 0
9*b + 10 = 0
b = -10/9
```

In MATLAB, you can do this symbolically using the symbolic math toolbox:

```
syms b
A = [b + 2 b; -4 5];
detA = det(A);
x = solve(detA == 0, b);
```

In MATLAB, `x` thus gives us:

```
x =

-10/9
```

---

## Sidenote

For a matrix to be invertible, either one of these should be met:

- None of the eigenvalues are equal to 0
- The determinant of the matrix is not equal to 0

Because you are forcing one of the eigenvalues to be 0, what you are essentially doing is determining the value of `b` that would generate an infinite number of solutions if you were to use this matrix and form a 2 x 2 system of equations.  You are also finding the value of `b` that would not allow this matrix to have an inverse.

To double check, if we substitute `b = -10/9` into the matrix, we get:

```
[ 8/9, -10/9]
[  -4,     5]
```

Finding the determinant of this matrix is indeed 0.  Also, one property of the determinant is that if one of the rows is a multiple of another row, the determinant is automatically 0.  We can clearly see this as the first row can be obtained by taking the second row and multiplying it by `-2/9`.

Comment: Just to add a few keywords to this awesome answer - `b = -10/9` will make `A` a *degenerate matrix*. Its *rank* is less than 2, which would be its rank if it is a full-rank matrix. There will be *free variable(s)* to the according equation set. The existence of a row that is a multiple of another is an example that could lower the *rank*, making the matrix *degenerate*. Thanks to @rayryeng for acutally solving this maths problem!